# Conduction Mode in PFC

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-factor-correction

At a Power-Factor-Correction (PFC) circuit, Why mostly using Continues Conduction Mode (CCM) for high power applications, ex. above 300 kW, and using Boundary Conduction Mode (BCM) or Discontinuous Conduction Mode (DCM) for low power applications?

Comment: Mostly EMC related - CCM has the lowest peak inductor current is and considered the 'quietest' method. CRM and DCM have higher peak inductor currents.

Comment: Check the research done by helloword922 when posting this question: [Active Power Factor Correction Operation Mode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73709/active-power-factor-correction-operation-mode).

Comment: I added an answer in the question linked to by @Huisman, mostly since the other question also covers the aspect of filtering.